# Not able to fetch request_id while making a ride request from Uber Ride Request Widget

Tags: uber-api

I am trying to integrate Uber Ride Request Widget within my app. I am able to load the Ride Request Button and load ride information as well.
However, once I click on Request Ride in the Uber Widget - I dont see any mechanism to fetch the ride request_id thus generated.
I am working in Sandbox environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the current ride using the rides client in the ios SDK. See the fetchCurrentRide() method to access all of the details about the in progress (current) ride.